# is there a quick way to remove all the old memory management in the old iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I find a nice project from github but it uses the old memory management model(non-ARC).
But my app uses ARC so xcode wont compile because of all the autorelease and dealloc stuff.

Is there a way to fix that?
for example, use both ARC and nonARC in one project, or automagically remove all the autorelease method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set ARC ignore flag `-fno-objc-arc` on the class files using not ARC - This is the quickest way to me!

Also you can refactor, GOTO: Edit>Refactor>Convert to Objective-C ARC

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has a tool built in, under the Edit->Refactor menu, to convert old code to ARC.  Alternatively, you can set custom compiler flags for individual files in your target's Compile Sources build phase.  If you want to *disable* ARC explicitly for a particular file, add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can either migrate the code to ARC. There are WWDC sessions just about this progress or you just tell Xcode that these classes aren't using ARC.

1. Option

   **Edit->Refactor->Convert To Objective-C ARC**
2. Option

Go to **Build Phases->Compile Sources** and add **-fno-objc-arc** as compiler flags.